# Give index numbers to the records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with various rows and columns. I want to add a column named `df_index` in the `df` which contains values that numbers all the records. For example: the `df_index` value for the 1st record should be `df_1`, for 2nd record it should be `df_2`, that goes up to the last record in `df`.

Please see that each value in `df_index` should be of the format `df_{number}`.

Comment: Can I ask what the need for this is, given that a df already has an index which if you didn't specifically create would give an int64 index that is monotonic anyway

Comment: I am merging the two datasets on certain criteria. After the whole processing, i want to know which the record_number of dataset1 that got merged with record_num of dataset 2. Hence, for a better clarity and picture in my results, i wish to add this column.

Comment: Well that information is completely absent from your question, besides when you do a a merge you can pass param `indicator=True` this will add a column '_merge',  telling you whether the rows are `left_only/both/right_only'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['df_index'] = 'df_' + pd.Series(range(1, len(df)+1), index=df.index).astype(str)
```